# Youtube Player Inside Tabbed Activity Cause This Error

Tags: java, android, youtube

I have tabbed activity and I want to have youtube video on third tab.

here's my java :

```
public class FragmentTutorial extends YouTubePlayerFragment {

    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener;

    public FragmentTutorial() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) youTubePlayerView.findViewById(R.id.tutorial_youtube_player);

        onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo("3LiubyYpEUk");
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        };

        youTubePlayerView.initialize(PlayerConfig.API_KEY, onInitializedListener);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tutorial, container, false);
    }

}
```

and here's my XML :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.FragmentTutorial">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tutorial_youtube_player" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and here's my MainActivity :

```
class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new FragmentHome();
                case 1:
                    return new FragmentCatalog();
                case 2:
                    return new FragmentTutorial();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position){
                //
                //Your tab titles
                //
                case 0: return "Home";
                case 1: return "Catalog";
                case 2: return "Tutorial";
                default: return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

when I tried to run this code, I got this following error :

```
Error:(80, 28) error: incompatible types: FragmentTutorial cannot be converted to Fragment
```

what did I missed here? thank you...

Answer (score 2):

Probably it is caused by the wrong Fragment class, `YouTubePlayerFragment` extends `android.app.Fragment`, `FragmentPagerAdapter` requires `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and this cannot be converted

**Edit:**

try to use `android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` instead `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` (other fragments should extends `android.app.Fragment`)

Comment: any idea how to have youtube player inside tabbed fragment? because most tutorials suggest to use `extends Youtube***` not `extends fragment` as I need.

Comment: I have `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;` should I changed all of them into `v13`?

Comment: `FragmentPagerAdapter` should be from `v13` library