# extends YouTubePlayerFragment vs extends Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have tabbed activity and it runs well using this statement :

```
public class FragmentTutorial extends Fragment {

}
```

then suddenly, my client need to add youtube video inside this fragment. so I tried to use :

```
public class FragmentTutorial extends YouTubePlayerFragment {

}
```

and it turns me into this error message :

```
Error:(80, 28) error: incompatible types: FragmentTutorial cannot be converted to Fragment
```

I believe this because I use :

```
class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

}
```

in my `MainActivity.java`. how to solve this incompatibility between this 2 kind of fragments? I want to put youtube video inside that existing fragment. but youtube requires another type of fragment.

please help me... :-(

Comment: YouTubePlayerFragment is a subclass of Fragment. How are you getting that error?

Comment: not sure why, but Android Studio point to this line :         public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new FragmentBeranda();
                case 1:
                    return new FragmentKatalog();
                case 2:
                    return new FragmentTutorial();
            }
            return null;
        }

Comment: and it has this info : incompatible types, required : android.support.v4.app.Fragment, found : com.example.FragmentTutorial

Comment: If this is in a ViewPager, the Fragment v4 classes are not compatible with those the YouTube player API use, which are the modern fragments. Try using v13 Fragments with your ViewPager.

Comment: I've answered your previous question. Duplicated same problem:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955010/youtube-player-inside-tabbed-activity-cause-this-error/42955273)

Comment: how to change into v13 fragments while all my codes already use v4 fragments?

Comment: I tried to change `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;` into v13 but it seems it will cause another error.

Comment: You have to resolve this errors, there is no other solution